# supabase policy for users to insert only one row

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I have a table "policies_views" with user_id column and policy_id column, I am trying to create a policy to prevent inserting a record if user_id = auth.id() and class_id = request.class_id.

I created this function "can_create_view"

```
DECLARE
    record_exists BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    -- Check if a record exists with the provided user_id and policy_id
    SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM policies_views
        WHERE policies_views.user_id = auth.uid() AND policies_views.policy_id = policyid
    ) INTO record_exists;

    -- Return true if no record exists, false otherwise
    RETURN NOT record_exists;
END;
```

and I am using this function to create a new policy "users can create only one view for each policy", for insert and with checks can_create_view(policy_id)

I am always getting

```
{
    "code": "42501",
    "details": null,
    "hint": null,
    "message": "new row violates row-level security policy for table \"policies_views\""
}
```

I am weak in sql and not sure what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by setting the security to `Definer` for the function and used this function definition

```
BEGIN
    RETURN NOT (SELECT (EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM policies_views
        WHERE user_id = $1 AND policy_id = $2 
    )));
END;
```